# SQL query to retrieve columns from different tables in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want a SQL query that retrieves columns from different tables in Visual Basic 2010.

I have four tables like this:

1. `tblTeacher` consists of

   • `TID` (pk)
   • `TName`
2. `tblSubject` consists of

   • `SID` (pk)
   • `subName`
   • `TID` (fk)
   • `TMID` (fk)
3. `tblTime` consists of

   • `TMID` (pk)
   • `TMValue`
4. `tblLecture` consists of

   • `LecID` (pk)
   • `LecDate`
   • `TID` (fk)
   • `subID` (fk)
   • `TMID` (fk)

`tblLecture` is for registered Lectures. There is a one-to-many relationship between the tables, where`tblLecture` is many. Now my question is:

I want a SQL query that retrieves the registered Lectures and returns columns `LecID`, `LecDate`, `TName`, `subName`, `TMValue`. I want to view the results in a DataGridView.

How can I call this SQL in my project please? (In my project, I use an Access database and SQL.)

Comment: Can you clarify the question as it is unclear and will be closed if you do not provide more details ?

Comment: Do you have trouble writing the SQL code or how to use it in VB?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables together, like this:

```
SELECT LecID,LecDate,TName,subName,TMValue
FROM tblLecture l, tblTeacher t, tblSubject s, tblTime i
WHERE l.TID=t.TID
AND   l.subID=s.SID
AND   l.TMID=i.TMID
```

Furthermore I am wondering about your tblTime table. Are you sure you need it?